# Nodes stick when I go back - spritekit swift

Tags: sprite-kit, swift2

I have been making a game, my player can move through the level forwards and backwards.

The level is arround 5000 pixels wide.

When I get to the end and then travel back to the beginning the player starts to stick to the ground.

It feels like the nodes that make up the ground are being redrawn but now have the wrong physics body properties.

How do i fix this?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Well if you suspect that, why don't you print those properties and see what is going on... Also, you may find useful enabling visual physics representation by doing `skView.showsPhysics =  true`... It can be useful while development phase.

Comment: Thanks - skView.showsPhysics has helped me fix it, I was on top of another node! cheers.